# Nginx and subversion

Tags: centos, nginx, svn

I've been migrating some of my machines to be using nginx + php-fpm and ditched apache.
However this is not an easy task as I haven't found a way to serve subversion off http using nginx only. 
Is that even possible? I know apache offer the mod_dav_svn module and many more modules but I'm not sure nginx offer the equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK nginx has no svn/dav support at all.

The only way is to keep an Apache instance with mod_dav_svn module up and running and proxy all svn requests from nginx to Apache.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing right now - too bad I can't ditch Apache completely.

Comment: nginx has dav support. Not sure subversion works with it.

Comment: nginx has not full web_dav implementation so there is not possible to use svn with nginx

Comment: is it still the case now?

Comment: It looks like even the extended dav plugin for NginX will never support SVN... https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

Personally I just use svnserve, it seems lightweight enough and has handled all my subversion needs. Often people don't actually use the full feature set offered by using Apache.

Comment: Is it possible to use ldap authentication with svnserve?
That was why I switched from svnserve to apache, allowing me to easily manage people who had access to my repositories.

Comment: svnserve can use SASL which, if I remember correctly, can use LDAP. I have never tried it before, though. To be honest I'm not sure the setup time is worth it, Apache isn't that bad of a resource hog when it's not used for actual web serving.